# TextView Does Not Return Anything Android

Tags: parsing, null, textview, double, gettext

I have a function in Android wherein it gets the value returned by a `TextView` which are
`totalcost_venue`, `totalcost_apparel`, `totalcost_souvenir`, and `totalcost_caterer`.

The value is converted to double and after which I have to add those values. But I encountered an error when a particular `TextView` does not return any value. Any help will do. Thanks!

```
double totalcost_venue_finalconverted = Double.parseDouble(totalcost_venue.getText().toString());
double totalcost_apparel_finalconverted = Double.parseDouble(totalcost_apparel.getText().toString());
double totalcost_caterer_finalconverted = Double.parseDouble(totalcost_caterer.getText().toString());
double totalcost_souvenir_finalconverted =  Double.parseDouble(totalcost_souvenir.getText().toString());

double total = (totalcost_venue_finalconverted + totalcost_apparel_finalconverted + totalcost_caterer_finalconverted +totalcost_souvenir_finalconverted);

String total_all= Double.toString(total);

totalcost_all.setText(total_all);
String totalcost_final = totalcost_all.getText().toString();

double budget_converted = Double.parseDouble(budget_event);
double totalcost_converted = Double.parseDouble(totalcost_final);

if(budget_converted <= totalcost_converted){
                registerErrorMsg.setText(" Oops!! Already exceeded");
```

Comment: whats the exception you are getting?

Comment: These are my error in my Logcat

02-19 13:04:45.185: E/AndroidRuntime(9456): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-19 13:04:45.185: E/AndroidRuntime(9456): java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: ""
02-19 13:04:45.185: E/AndroidRuntime(9456):  at java.lang.StringToReal.invalidReal(StringToReal.java:63)
02-19 13:04:45.185: E/AndroidRuntime(9456):  at java.lang.StringToReal.parseDouble(StringToReal.java:248)
02-19 13:04:45.185: E/AndroidRuntime(9456):  at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:295)

Comment: yup looks like you are missing validations, you should check if the field is empty and if the field has a double value before trying to parse to double.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Double.parseDouble()` may be throwing an exception if it recieves a null value, or it is recieves text.

To solve your issue with a null value, you could add the following check:

```
double totalcost_venue_finalconverted = 0;

if(!totalcost_venue.getText().toString().equals("")){
    totalcost_venue_finalconverted = Double.parseDouble(totalcost_venue.getText().toString());
}
```

Comment: what will I do if the textview returned is empty? @Matt Clark

Comment: i dunno... what do you want to do? the above will set the value as 0 if the field is left empty.